# Embedding server side javascript frameworks in a Java desktop application?

Tags: java, javascript

I've read that it's possible to embed Rhino into your Java application. Narwhal is also built on top of it by default and I was directed to http://narwhaljs.org/ which actually no longer exists.

I would love to know of anything similar to nodejs,ringojs which can be embedded into my Java desktop application.

Comment: The key phrase to search for tutorials, references and such is **Java Scripting API**. It really is fun, _if_ you have a field of application.